# How to deal with "mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/2006): MySQL server has gone away" error while trying to connect an offline db with heroku's ClearDB?

Tags: php, mysql, heroku

[image]

I am trying to host a PHP-based website on Heroku. For that, I'm using ClearDB as my online database

For doing so, I added a new code to *config.inc.php* in *C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin*:
The code is as follows:

````
/* Heroku remote server */
$i++;
$cfg["Servers"][$i]["host"] = "*pasted hostname*"; //provide hostname
$cfg["Servers"][$i]["user"] = "*username*"; //user name for your remote server
$cfg["Servers"][$i]["password"] = "*password*"; //password
$cfg["Servers"][$i]["auth_type"] = "config"; // keep it as config```
````

After doing this and refreshing my XAMP, I was able to get an option to choose the server I want to shift to, but when I click it, I was getting the error that I'm showing above.

Answer (score 1):

Server gone away is a generic error, the actual issue is that you're using invalid settings to try and connect to it.

On the host running phpmyadmin, you should try connecting to the mysql server using the `mysql` command

Something like `mysql -h SomeHost -u root -p` and debug that way before plugging the information back into PHPMyAdmin